# Python: why are buffer objects not picklable?

Tags: python, pickle

It seems that a `buffer` object is not picklable. Why is that so? Earlier, pickling didn't threw an exception but unpickling did not work, see [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue8323). So I guess the pickling was wrong. Why wasn't it just fixed so that unpickling would have worked? I searched a bit around and it seems as this was already requested as early as in 2005 [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-April/052707.html). Now, I guess it would be quite easy to make it picklable in a right way with an appropriate `__reduce__` function.

Comment: The reason is explained in your first link. Richard Oudkerk writes: "buffer is only used in Python 2.x. Python 2.7 is in bugfix mode, so this issue will not change now."